# I am facing a problem in uilabel when i set value "Welcome \n\(user!)"

Tags: ios, swift

`welcomeLabel.text = "Welcome \n\(user!)"` it just show Welcome it does not show next line

welcomeLabel.text = "Welcome \n(user!)"
output:
"Welcome"
expected:
"Welcome
user.value
"
hence i used new uilabel()
so what i have to do next

Comment: Did you the the number of line of the label to 2 ? By default labels show only one line.

Answer (score 2):

You must assign `numberOfLines` to 0 to enable multiple lines

```
welcomeLabel.numberOfLines = 0 //Or how many lines you want
```

Btw, It's hard to read continuous string with special characters like "\n" etc. You may consider this:

```swift
welcomeLabel.text = """
Welcome
\(user!)
"""
```